# Word for Copyright holder

Tags: single-word-requests, legalese

I'm writing an essay on Intellectual Property Rights in the Digital Age, and I have the following sentence:

> DRM is an instrument to protect Copyright, and therefore it should be implemented in such way that it respects the rights of users and [X] alike.

Here, [X] should be a word for the copyright holder that juxtaposes with the word "users". Currently I have "copyright holders", and previously I had "creators". None of them satisfy me because I feel like a composite term damages the juxtaposition effect, and because the creator and the copyright holder may be different people.

What would be an appropriate word?

Comment: Perhaps "owners".

Comment: Use "copyright holder" or "owner" and don't let worry about how the sentence sounds get in the way of clear communication :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Owner" is the right word; copyrights are property, and that property, in whole or in part, can be transferred.  As you note in a comment, the current owner may not be the creator.  The copyright, or some of the rights it confers, may have been transferred; or the copyrighted material may have been created as a work for hire.

"Holder" is also acceptable.

See [bitlaw on copyright](https://www.bitlaw.com/copyright/ownership.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're referring to, in your context, those who have created whatever intellectual property: the **authors** of the copyrights.

Comment: I point out in my question that the creator/author of a work is not necessarily the copyright holder of said work, which is why something such as "author" is ill-suited.